# products settings synchronization

Tags: sql, sql-server, architecture, websocket

I have two products, called A and B. Both products share some setting lets say X. Product A is a regular windows service that runs a regular C# timer that perform some action each X second. In product B, the user has the ability to change this parameter X. How can I make product A to know about the changes of the setting made in B? The only thing in common for product A and B are a Microsoft SQL Server database (where the settings will be written to from B as well).

I need some method/architecture that B can notify A when there are changed settings in the database, there are a lot of settings like X also, so should be a general solution.

Thank you!

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do.  You say that product A runs a timer and that an action is performed.  Are you using SQL server's job queue to trigger the action every X second.  What is the action?

Comment: Sorry for that, both products consists of windows services and the action product A performs is reading some data from a hardware device, however this action is not relevant for the synchronization, thank you for the note.

Comment: If the services are on the same machine, why not have a file 'touched'... and if they aren't, why not have an SQL field called `updated_at`, so that the settings validity are checked every time action A is performed?

Comment: Thank you Myst. However, while the method you suggest with updated_at field would work, its not the solution I would prefer since it would cause a lot of unnecessary database requests, the action A is often performed each 5 seconds and the value/settings often changed maybe once a week or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a message queue.  I believe there is one baked into SQL Server (it's been a while though).  Your batch job just needs to check the queue each time it runs for new config values.

Comment: This means that every time my action performs, I need to poll this queue for new settings. How is this different than just polling the settings table and sorting on a updated_at column? I would like to have it event driven since my action performs very often, sometimes even at 2-3 seconds intervals.

Comment: Fundamentally it isn't any different, queues are just tables that are highly optimized for pulling records off the head, and only delivering them once.  You can absolutely build your own by creating a table which has some sort of "received" flag, which you can set after pulling the setting off the table.